# Running container VM on google cloud compute

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, containers

If I pass a startup script to google compute engine with a container vm, will it run it inside or outside the container?

I need to install some drivers, and the best way to do it seems to be with a startup script. The container and the machine are running different linux operating systems, so I have to manage that.

Answer (score 1):

Any script that you place in [GCE metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) will run in the VM and not in the container. If you are using kubernetes you might want to try this [beta feature](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/abstractions/init-containers/)